# How to prevent appending to a list to fill gpu memory

Tags: python, memory, pytorch, gpu

I run a model with pytorch with batch inference. I want to save the output from that model to a list, because I need it later for other calculations. The problem is, that if I append the output from my model to my list "output", it fills the gpu memory.
The output from the model is a list.
Is there a way to move the list to RAM?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        output = []
        with torch.no_grad():
            for i in input_split:
                try:
                    preds = model(i)                        
                    output.append(preds)          
                    del preds   
                    gc.collect()
                    torch.cuda.empty_cache()    

                except RuntimeError as e:
                    print("Failed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the tensors you get from `preds = model(i)` are still in GPU.

You can just take them out of the GPU before appending them to the list

```
output = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for i in input_split:
        preds = model(i)
        output.append(preds.cpu())
```

And when you want to use them again in GPU then just put them into GPU one by one

```
for data in output:
    data = data.cuda()
```

## Edit 1. The Detectron2

This is similar to the above answer, except a little bit more complicated.

The output of `Detectron2` is `list[dict]`. Which means if you have more than 1 images in the batch you'll have to create an empty list as buffer, like

```
output = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for i in input_split:
        preds = model(i)
        
        buffer = []
        for pred in preds:
            pred['instances']['pred_boxes'] = pred['instances']['pred_boxes'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['scores'] = pred['instances']['scores'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['pred_classes'] = pred['instances']['pred_classes'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['pred_masks'] = pred['instances']['pred_masks'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['pred_keypoints'] = pred['instances']['pred_keypoints'].cpu()
            buffer.append(pred)
        output.append(buffer)
```

You maybe able to use pointer and get rid of buffer like this too

```
output = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for i in input_split:
        preds = model(i)
        
        for pred in preds:
            pred['instances']['pred_boxes'] = pred['instances']['pred_boxes'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['scores'] = pred['instances']['scores'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['pred_classes'] = pred['instances']['pred_classes'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['pred_masks'] = pred['instances']['pred_masks'].cpu()
            pred['instances']['pred_keypoints'] = pred['instances']['pred_keypoints'].cpu()
        output.append(preds)
```

Comment: This does not work:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/ML_Seg/AdelaiDet/demo/demo_inference.py", line 307, in <module>
    output.append(preds.cpu())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cpu'

Comment: So `preds` is a list? Then you'll need to separate all those elements into tensors. Like `a, b, c = model(i)` instead. If you don't understand what this means then put the code of the `model` in the main question.

Comment: Im using detectron2: https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/models.html for image segmentation. The link contains the output format . Does this help? Thx for your help!

Comment: Is `i` a batch of multiple images or just 1 image? 1 image is a lot easier to deal with for Detectron2

Comment: i is a batch of multiple images (e.g 5). It works if the image resolution is below 800x800, but I need it to be 1000x1000. If I dont append the output to the list, only 4gb of gpu memory is used. So appending to the list definitely is the issue.

Comment: Also is the task `instances_segmentation` or `semantic_segmentation` or `panoptic_segmentation`? I'll answer for `instance` first but please provide the result of `print(preds[0].keys())`

Comment: I need it for instances_segmentation and panoptic_segmentation. Output of keys: dict_keys(['instances'])

Comment: It just `instance` then. I'm writing the answer.

Comment: I needed to modify your code a little. 
for pred in preds:
                        pred['instances'].pred_boxes = pred['instances'].pred_boxes.tensor.cpu()
                        pred['instances'].scores = pred['instances'].scores.cpu()
                        pred['instances'].pred_classes = pred['instances'].pred_classes.cpu()
                        pred['instances'].pred_masks = pred['instances'].pred_masks.cpu()
                        #pred['instances'].pred_keypoints = pred['instances'].pred_keypoints.cpu()
                        buffer.append(pred)
output.append(buffer)
Thx!